# How to get viewport size in qt

Tags: qt, opengl

How to get the size of the viewport in pixels and convert it to Vec2f in qt opengl? I need it for my shader.

I know for the getWindowSize().

Comment: Probably wrong, but perhaps worth investigation: override resizeEvent

Comment: Well I need Vec2f in my shader and I am use glUniform2fv() function. When I do Vec2f castin I get an error that Vec2f identifier is not found

Comment: I see a bit of conflict in answers and comments. Perhaps you should edit the question and tell where, when and how you are going to use the Vec2f containing viewport size. Also, a bit of code is always good in a SO question, a good code snippet speaks more than a thousand words of explanation.

Answer (score 5):

The same way you get the viewport size in any other framework... GLint vp [4]; `glGetIntegerv (GL_VIEWPORT, vp);` note this will return an integer array of 4 parameters - the same ones you would pass to `glViewport (...)`.

Good software will be written in such a way that you do not need to ask the OpenGL state machine for this information, probably by keeping the viewport size as a cached local state. But aside from doing that, this is the only way to know your viewport size. That is because it is independent of your window size, so knowing the size of your window from Qt will not help you to solve this issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `QWidget::width()` and `QWidget::height()` out of the resizeGL event to obtain the window's sizes and determine your viewport dimensions from that. *Do not* set the viewport in the `QGLWidget::resizeGL` handler; you should use that to make adjustment to things that depend on the screen size and which are expensive to change, like textures used for a post-processing FBO.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reimplement the resizeGL method to get it right. See the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#resizeGL) and [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtopengl/qglwidget.html#details) for details. You would write something like this:

```
void resizeGL(int w, int h)
{
    ...
    Vec2f myVec2f((GLint)w, (GLint)h);
    ...
}
```

Once you have the width and height that way, the conversion to Vec2f is simple enough. Basically just `Vec2f(width, height)` construction.

You can also use `QWidget::size()`, or `QWidget::width()`, and `QWidget::height()` if you need to obtain those outside the context of the resize event.